# What is the correct terminology for describing the modes of application of a product to a plant?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, technical, phrasing

What is the correct word (or sequences of words) for describing the following two processes?

1) The application of an agricultural product, such as a pesticide, to a plant, through the leaves. If you need an example sentence to work with, how about:

This product is for ... only.

My first trial is to fill the dots with "foliar application". Another idea that comes to mind is: "on leaves application" or "application on leaves". I don't like any of the options I came up with.

2) Same situation as above but this time the application of the product is through the roots of the plant. In order to fill the dots, I came up with "radical application" which I think is an entire different concept though, and "through roots application" which I like a bit better but I'm not sure if it is correct.

In short I'm looking for technical terms for filling the dots.

A sidenote: for "correct" I mean either the technical terms or the words generally accepted and used to express the concept I described.

Comment: *application to the leaves*, *application to the roots*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In agriculture the correct terminology is 'foliar application' for the leaves and 'application of a systemic herbicide/insecticide' for the roots.
In the case of your example sentence, 'This product is for foliar application only', would be correct. The systemic product would depend on the method of application as systemic products can be foliar, soil or water applied.